# How do I dynamically link between two tabels

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table and the data in one of the fields is a field name in another table.

I would like to extract the data from the second table based on that field. 
example:

- Table `A` has a column called `FldName`. `FldName` has the value `Number001`.
- Table `B` has a column called `Number001`.

I'd like to extract the value of `B.Number001`.

Not too versed in SQL so detailed answers are appreciated.

Comment: Please do yourself a favour and change the schema, will save you a lot of trouble going forward.

Comment: First of all, Thank You for taking the time to answer my question. I'll try it. Secondly, I agree that the schema  is horrible. but it is not mine. I am trying to write a report based on a software package :(

Answer (score 1):

**Sample Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE TABLEA (ID INT , FldName SYSNAME)
GO
INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES(1 , 'Number001')
GO

CREATE TABLE TABLEB (Number001 INT)
GO
INSERT INTO TABLEB VALUES (1),(2),(3)
GO
```

**Procedure to get data**

```
CREATE PROC get_DataFromTableB 
 @FieldID INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
Declare @Sql Nvarchar(max), @ColName SYSNAME;

IF (@FieldID IS NULL) 
 BEGIN
   SET @Sql = N'SELECT * FROM TABLEB'
    Exec sp_executesql @Sql
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN
   SELECT @ColName = FldName FROM TABLEA
   SET @Sql = N'SELECT '+QUOTENAME(@ColName)+' FROM TABLEB'
   Exec sp_executesql @Sql
 END
END
```

**Procedure call**

You can pass the procedure an `ID` of the `FieldName` from `TableA` or no parameter at all.

If the ID is passed it will only return that column from TableB and if no ID is passed it will simply do a `select * from TableB`

To get only `Number001` field from tableB

```
Exec get_DataFromTableB 1
```

To get all the fields from TableB

```
Exec get_DataFromTableB
```